# Do I have to report empty bank accounts on form 8938 "Statement of Specified Foreign Financial Assets"

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, foreign-income

I have empty bank accounts that I no longer use. It's unclear to me if I should report those accounts on form 8938.

Comment: I don't think an empty bank account is an asset, provided it is literally empty.

Answer (score 1):

According to IRS.gov, you have to report empty foreign bank accounts on [Form 8938](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8938.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408044804/https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8938.pdf)) “Statement of Specified Foreign Financial Assets". From https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/basic-questions-and-answers-on-form-8938#ReportQ2 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408044501/https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/basic-questions-and-answers-on-form-8938)):

> Q2. If I have to file Form 8938, am I required to report all of my specified foreign financial assets regardless of whether the assets have a de miminis maximum value during the tax year?
>
> If you meet the applicable reporting threshold, **you must report all of your specified foreign financial assets, including the specified foreign financial assets that have a [de minimis](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=De_minimis&oldid=868230780#Taxation) maximum value during the tax year**.  For exceptions to reporting, see Exceptions to Reporting on page 6 of the [instructions for Form 8938](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8938.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408044536/https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8938.pdf)).

Comment: For tax purposes, since pretty much all forms require reporting in rounded whole dollars, I think "de minimis value" may refer to $0.00 < X < $0.50 (exclusive).  Or do you have a definition?  (your link discusses treatment of de minimis, but does not define it except in the context of bond discount)

Answer (score 0):

I'll first note that I'm not a US citizen or resident, so others may be better qualified to answer.

However, having found a copy of the form, part VI, question 4 asks for the "Maximum value of asset during tax year (check box that applies)" and the first box is labelled "**$0**–$50,000", suggesting to me that empty accounts should be included.